# How to stop an overlay component/image "blocking" touches of a button in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For my (homemade) transition system, I have an overlay image identical to my background that fades in and out when navigating.

As this always lies "on top" of everything, it seems to block interactions with buttons (e.g. TouchableOpacity). Seems reasonable enough, but how can I disable this for a certain component?

(A workaround might be to remove the overlay once it's at opacity 0 anyway, but it would still be nice to know)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: pointerEvents 'none' ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents

Comment: Any solutions on this? I'm coming across this issue now as well.